# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [650, 1300]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to run a multivariate (multiple y) regression algorithm. The code is as follows.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = data[['PM', 'Na', 'Cl', 'Al', 'Si', 'Ti']].values
y = data[['AD', 'SS']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.flatten(), test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
```

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [650, 1300] at the splitting step.

I tried searching on google but couldn't find anything. Someone please guide me on how to select multiple y values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`X` and `y` don't have the same length.

To see for yourself, evaluate with `X.shape` and `y.shape`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The data has same number of rows for all columns. There are 2 features in y and it is adding them instead of taking them individually.

Comment: (650, 6)
(650, 2)

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [650, 1300]

Comment: You' re welcome. Yes, that's what I'm trying to make you understand, that y's dimensions are messed up. I can't know exactly how to reshape your data without, well, having access to your data. Numpy's reshape and/or concatenate can help you achieve what you want.

Comment: I tried reshaping the data, but it is giving the same error with more number of rows.

Comment: You have to get X and y to the same length. You sure you're doing this correctly? If you do, then maybe you have another error.

Answer (score 0):

First, check for the size of data sets after the train test split by doing .shape.
Sometimes the reason for the error in this data is the ordering. X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test and so on which is correct in this solution. Try using a simple 1-D array for the y dataset instead of converting it from 2d to 1-d in the runtime of the train test which causes the inconsistencies.